# Filter index by str.startswith()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe index of dates, ranging from 2001 to 2015.  I want to isolate the 2015 dates.  I want to take advantage of the format -- all dates starting with the full year - e.g. 2004abc...

I would like to simply create a new dataframe, of all elements where the date starts with 2015.

When the column is a string, I am able to do it like this:

```
df1 = df[df['some column name']=='some string']
```

But when I try

```
df[df['some column name']str.startwith('2015')]
```

I get an error.

Is there anyway to do this?

The error I get is just not recognizing the 'some column name' in df['some column name'].

Edit:  Just a short edit to say that I think the problem here was due to trying to filter on the index, which might be handled differently that a regular column.  See @Jezrael's answer below which worked.

Comment: `df['some column name'].str.startwith('2015')`

Comment: @ZakS, For future readers, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50122470/edit) with the exact error you get?

Comment: @Wen, I am still getting an error.  It does not like the column I am filtering on.  in my case the column is called "Date" and the error I get is just "Date".

Comment: Hello @COLDSPEED, the question you linked this to is asking how to filter on a column name, but my problem is different.  It is asking about the values in the column. Could you open the question please?

Comment: @ZakS - I think need `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('2015')]`

Comment: @ZakS - Another solution is `df.filter(regex='^2015')`

Comment: this works great.